# iphone MultiTasking?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hello I'm trying to get the multitasking work properly, but unfortunately I'm kinda lost. My problem is when I re-enter the game, it takes several seconds for the game to come back and show the pause screen. My question is; is there any way to put some sort of loading screen until the game comes back, so I can at least indicate that its not frozen? I've never used Xcode directly. I'm using Unity 3d to build my game. I made a little bit of research and if I'm not mistaken I'm supposed to use "applicationDidEnterBackground" app delegate method. My question is How can I put a custom loading screen using that method in Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In -applicationDidEnterBackground:, you're given the opportunity to "clean up" the UI before the screenshot is taken. Apple says you should remove "sensitive data" (the screenshots might be persisted to "disk"?), but it also lets you do other things. In one app, we hide the label on a countdown timer so it doesn't appear to jump when you switch back to the app.

To change the "loading screen", simply display a full-screen view over the other views and remove it in -applicationWillEnterForeground:. Alternatively, pause the game in the first place!

(Really, you should be pausing the game in -applicationWillResignActive: which happens when the user double-taps home or the user receives a SMS/notification. I'm pretty sure it's called when the app is backgrounded, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have this code inside the applicationDidEnterBackground function.

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: _window.frame];

[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

[_window insertSubview:myImage aboveSubview:view];
[myImage release];

This supposed to put the Background image when application goes background, but for some reason its not working.

Comment: I'm also pausing my game in unity, but you can't see the pause screen until the game loads and enters the foreground. That's why I want to put some loading screen while the user re-enter the game.

Comment: `-addSubview:` always sticks the view at the top, so it's more likely to do the right thing in the event that `view` is nil or not a direct subview or so. It's also possible that Unity catches UIApplicationWillBecomeInactiveNotification or UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and pauses the Unity renderer itself, causing the pause screen to not display until rendering resumes. Without seeing their source code, it's hard to tell.